# What would be the state of the art image captioning deep learning model?

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, state-of-the-art, text-generation, model-request

I saw a couple of architectures, like CNN-LSTM, with and without attention model, use of Glove vector, self-critical models, etc. I am overwhelmed looking at different notebooks and architectures, came here for a guidance.  I am looking to build a personal project on image annotations. Also, if I wanted to use this deep learning model together with TFX pipeline, what would be the best type of architecture I can go with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple of Kaggle Kernels, Notebooks and Tutorials for Image Captioning.

- [Kaggle Kernel | Neural Image Captioning:  ->](https://www.kaggle.com/sauravmaheshkar/neural-image-captioning)
- [Kaggle Kernel | Show Attend and Tell](https://www.kaggle.com/aritrag/show-attend-and-tell)
- [Kaggle Kernel | Flickr Image Captioning : TPU, TF2 & Glove](https://www.kaggle.com/ratthachat/flickr-image-captioning-tpu-tf2-glove)
- [Tensorflow Tutorial | Image captioning with visual attention](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/image_captioning)
- [Show and Tell: A Neural Image Caption Generator by Vinyals et al.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.4555v2.pdf)